# Web service client and server

Tags: java, web-services

I am a webservice beginner. Is it required to have two different projects having separate EAR for developing a Web Service and its client both?(JAX-WS based)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SOAP via JAX-WS you can develop the client using any programming language and technology you like (as long as it knows about SOAP).

So, yes, you should definitely separate server and client, even if you develop the client in Java, too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it'd be recommended to do so, to keep a minimum level of organization.

By the way, if you are coding your client for a desktop environment, you would have a resulting `.jar` and only the server would be packed in an `.ear`.